# Does the word "Vaccum" exist?

Tags: nouns, orthography, meaning, doubled-consonants

If yes, does it have the same meaning of ***vacuum***?

Ref:

- [Vacuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum) (Wikipedia)
- [Vaccum.org](http://www.vaccum.org/) (dead link / domain not in use; verified on 28.12.2020).

Both the sites define the same meaning, but the spelling differs.

[Some dictionaries](http://onelook.com/?w=vaccum) also have an entry for *vaccum* which links to *vacuum*.

Comment: The first site you linked to doesn't mention the spelling _vaccum_ at all though. And I don't believe you should take the second site too seriously, as it has links to http://www.vaccuum.org and http://ultravide.org (the last one being for the French word _ultravide_, which doesn't exist either).

Comment: Another odd variant spelling appears to be _vacumn_. Although that variant is very hard to find in [dictionaries](http://www.onelook.com/?w=vacumn&ls=a), it can be found on some [websites](http://www.norprowebstore.com/apple-peeling-machines-cherry-pitters/norpro-apple-master-with-vacumn-base-clamp-865-1095.aspx), and in some [scientific literature](http://www.google.com/search?q=vacumn&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=vacumn&hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&ei=GLocUd3iGsik2gXYk4D4Ag&start=10&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42452523,d.b2I&fp=77ba4f424f36d5eb&biw=1228&bih=870) as well.

Comment: Sometimes there are just mistakes that unfortunately get repeated.

Comment: Re: vaccum.org It is very common for website domain names to take the form of words which are often misspelled so that they can get advertising hits.

Comment: The "Wellccome" on the vaccum.org site ought to give you a hint.

Comment: @KitFox,good point didnt notice that :)

Comment: Ironically, vacuum.org is currently available.

Comment: Related question (and answers): [Who changed the way vacumn was spelled 40 years ago?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/443831/who-changed-the-way-vacumn-was-spelled-40-years-ago)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=vaccum) says "vaccum: A word presumably used by those who do not know that the correct spelling is "vacuum".

More seriously, [NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vacuum%2C+vaccum&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) thinks *vaccum* doesn't exist at all.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly it does, because you and the second website you link to use it. If you’re asking if it’s the normal spelling for the word describing a space empty of matter, then it is not. The normal spelling is *vacuum*. The Corpus of Contemporary American English has 2 records for it, against 5810 for *vacuum*. The figures for the British National Corpus are 1 and 919.

Comment: I checked [both instances](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/x3.asp?xx=1&w11=vaccum&) and they look like typos (one journalistic, one from a thriller); I disagree that establishes usage. We might just as well claim 'websyte' is an alternative spelling of 'website' if we found one instance of it.

Comment: I don't think I said that.

Comment: What exactly are you saying then though? One questionable spelling establishes in ~6000 establishes an alternative spelling. Or the whimsical use by the site vaccum.org with their "Wellccome" message? I don't think either of these establishes an alternative spelling.

Comment: Where it is used, it has the same meaning as _vacuum_, but I don't recommend it, and I didn't say that I did.

Comment: I never thought you recommended it. I just wondered if you were suggesting a handful of examples established an alternative spelling. But no. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score -2):

But, but, but ...  [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=vaccum) lists "vaccum':

> A word presumably used by those who do not know that the correct
> spelling is "vacuum".